# Using pop-ups or pop-up metaphor in responsive web application design

Tags: popup, responsive

Does anyone have experience in using pop-up windows or pop-up metaphor in responsive design? I could imagine this could be challenging.. but perhaps doable?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this google screenshot:

[image]